# ZF2 PHPUnit assert Exception

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I try to see if an exception is thrown from my controller

In my controller I have a "throw new \ RuntimeException"

In my test, if I put setExpectedException ('RuntimeException'), my assertion fails if the full test fails

What should I do?

```
class myController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function indexAction() {
        ...
        throw new \RuntimeException;
    }
}

class myControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase {
    public function testIndexAction() {
        ...
        $this->setExpectedException('RuntimeException');
        ...
        $this->dispatch('/');
   }
}
```

Output with 'setExpectedException' :

> 1) ApplicationTest\Controller\myControllerTest::testIndexAction Failed
>   asserting that exception of type "\RuntimeException" is thrown.

Output without :

> 1) ApplicationTest\Controller\myControllerTest::testIndexAction with
>   data set #0 (false, '', 1) RuntimeException:
>
> /home/bruno/public_html/jacuzzi/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/myController.php:60
>   /home/bruno/public_html/jacuzzi/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php:82
>   /home/bruno/public_html/jacuzzi/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:444
>   /home/bruno/public_html/jacuzzi/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:205
>   /home/bruno/public_html/jacuzzi/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php:118
>   /home/bruno/public_html/jacuzzi/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php:93
>   /home/bruno/public_html/jacuzzi/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:444
>   /home/bruno/public_html/jacuzzi/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:205
>   /home/bruno/public_html/jacuzzi/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php:314
>   /home/bruno/public_html/jacuzzi/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:282
>   /home/bruno/public_html/jacuzzi/module/Application/test/ApplicationTest/Controller/myControllerTest.php:188

PS: I use ZF 2.4.4 and PHPUnit 4.7.8

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a dataProvider to allow the testAction to iterate over potential input data - hence the `with data set` in the output `ApplicationTest\Controller\myControllerTest::testIndexAction with data set #0 (false, '', 1)`

I would hazard a guess that your data provider is providing some cases which are sucessful and therefore shouldn't trigger the exception, and some cases which should trigger the exception, resulting in failures in either case if you are always or never telling PHPUnit to expect the exception.

My typical approach to cases like these is to pass the exception as one of the parameters to the test function, and use `NULL` to represent cases where an exception should not be expected. You can then use a construct like the following within the test function in order to conditionally expect the exception:

```
if ($expectedException !== null) {
    $this->setExpectedException($expectedException);
}
```

Comment: The last parameter from the data set is used for this (1 -> error msg 1)

Comment: Any other test cases in the data set? Are they definitely shielded from the setExpectedException call by some sort of conditional?

Comment: There are other cases, but it does not raise an exception

Comment: Do you mean that the other case(s) do not raise an exception within the system under test (as expected in your first snippet of output)? Or that they do not raise an exception that causes the test to fail (similarly to the second snippet)? Can you answer the second question I have asked - "Are they [the test cases] definitely shielded from the setExpectedException call by some sort of conditional?"

Comment: The other cases raise no exception but that's normal they do not need. In this case, the exception is raised because there is an connection error